# How to bind data to a row in a RecyclerView using data binding?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-databinding

I want to show some image and text in RecyclerView row using data binding. Code is running without any error but the data is not showing in the RecyclerView.

**reward_item.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>
            <import type="android.view.View" />
            <variable
                name="recipes"
                type="com.prasona.android.indiancusine.Model.NameModel" />
        </data>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardElevation="5dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/name_textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/recipeimageView"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/recipeimageView"
                        android:text="@{recipes.recipeName}"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/recipeimageView"
                        android:layout_width="180dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dinner"
                        app:imageUrl="@{image.imageUrl}"/>
                </RelativeLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
```

Here is my adapter:

```
import android.databinding.BindingAdapter;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.databinding.ViewDataBinding;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;


import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by admin on 14-12-2017.
 */

public class RewardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RewardAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<SampleModel> model;

    public RewardAdapter(List<SampleModel> model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ViewDataBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                R.layout.rewarded_item, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ViewDataBinding viewDataBinding = holder.getViewDataBinding();

//        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.image,model.get(position));
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.recipeName, model.get(position));
        viewDataBinding.setVariable(BR.imageUrl, model.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != model ? model.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ViewDataBinding viewBinding;

        public ViewHolder(ViewDataBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());

            viewBinding = binding;
            viewBinding.executePendingBindings();
        }

        public ViewDataBinding getViewDataBinding() {
            return viewBinding;
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear at all what are you trying to bind. In your code you have the SampleModel class which seems to be the model for your row, but in your layout you've declared a variable recipes of type Model.NameModel. Later in the row layout you also use an image variable for the ImageView.

I'm going to assume that your row model is the SampleModel class that you use in the adapter and that it contains text(for the TextView) and a String representing the image url for that entry. To make binding work you should:

Declare a SampleModel variable in the code and use it for your views:

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View" />
    <variable
        name="recipes"
        type="the.package.of.the.class.SampleModel" />
</data>
```

which will be used in the layout:

```
<TextView
    ...
    android:text="@{recipes.recipeName}"/>
<ImageView
    ...
    app:imageUrl="@{recipes.imageUrl}"/>
```

The SampleModel class should be a class which extends BaseObservable and exposes the two fields that we used above:

```
class SampleModel extends BaseObservable {
    private String recipeName;
    private String imageUrl;

    @Bindable
    public String getRecipeName() {
         return recipeName;
    }

    @Bindable
    public String getImageUrl() {
         return imageUrl;
    }
}
```

The adapter will need to be changed to use the exact binding class:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    RewardItemBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
            R.layout.rewarded_item, parent, false);
    // update the ViewHolder constructor to receive a RewardItemBinding parameter instead of the super class
    return new ViewHolder(binding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    RewardItemBinding viewDataBinding = holder.getViewDataBinding();
    viewDataBinding.setRecipes(model.get(position));
}
```

This will set the data for the two views from the model. The problem is with the ImageView which doesn't have a setter for the imageUrl attribute that we used in the layout and the binding framework will not know how to bind the data to the view. To handle this you can use a BindingAdapter like below:

```
// declare this method in one of your classes(notice the static modifier)
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
public static void bindImage(ImageView imageView, String imageUrl) {
    // use Glide to setup the image
}
```

Comment: Here what is RewardItemBinding class consist.

Comment: @ChetanJoshi That class is generated by the databinding library from the layout file. Its name is constructed from the layout's file name(reward_item.xml)  and the word *Binding*.